# Regular Expression: Match Hex/Key Strings

Tags: regex

I have tried creating a regular expression myself to do this, but honestly my mind is so boggled with it right now that I must ask for help... This may be helpful for people in the future as well.

I have the following input templates:

```
06-6A-BF-05-AF-84-DF-A4-23-7C-BE-B4-6C-95-D7
JK1T-XTSRV-2HC4D-RP4S7-ZMKRG
```

I need to pick out strings like these two from an input string. An input string may look like this:

```
JK1T-XTSRV-2HC4D-RP4S7-ZMKRG
FDGF-A1S0M-5M8XJ-T08WC-BCZSJ
C6-6C-1C-17-B7-EE-BE-EA-E3-7C-EF-23-6C-12-F1
asdf234 ,f C6-324_EE
```

In this case, the following would be returned:

```
JK1T-XTSRV-2HC4D-RP4S7-ZMKRG, FDGF-A1S0M-5M8XJ-T08WC-BCZSJ, C6-6C-1C-17-B7-EE-BE-EA-E3-7C-EF-23-6C-12-F1
```

Thus, the regular expression would need to have the following restrictions to match a string:

- 15 two character (numbers or letters) pairs separated by `-`
- 5 four character (numbers or letters) pairs separated by `-`

**What regular expression will match these?**

Comment: The first two input string examples are neither hex strings nor match the textual description "5 four-character pairs [sic] separated by `-`"

Comment: The first of the strings you mention seems to be `hex` whereas the other is not ? Do you really care about each 2 or 4 character text to be a hex value or not ?

Comment: @JanDvorak edited :) sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use two regular expressions:

```
(\w{2}-){14}\w{2}
\w{4}-(\w{5}-){3}\w{5}
```

The second type is actually one four char and four five char.

Test 1:
http://fiddle.re/h3ve6

Test 2:
http://fiddle.re/3a5e6

Comment: Sure I can do two... Thanks... also sorry for messing up on the restrictions, I'm very tired :)

Comment: It appears that the second one is matching two in the example case FDGF-A1S0M-5M8XJ-T08WC-BCZSJ - it's matching FDGF-A1S0M-5M8XJ-T08WC-BCZSJ and T08WC-

Comment: Sorry, I did say I hadn't tested the second one and someone edited my answer to remove that bit! ;) let me have a look...

Comment: Ah ok I see the confusion, I had to use a group for the repeating middle part so `group(1)` will always return a partial result. If you do `find()` in a loop and then just use `group(0)` each time it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the effort! Accepted again.

Comment: Hey, I'm having some problems with this again, if you run your second test in JavaScript mode, it fails; I need to find multiple matches in a single string.